# Text Dependent Voicer Verification - Authentication with voice

Tags: voice-recognition, voice

I would like to build simple text dependent voicer verification system: simple application that will receive wav/mp3 file with recorded word/sentence and will check if that word/sentence is spoken by given user and if the word is correct. Basically I want to authenticate user with voice and password from previously recorded and processed records. What is the simplest approach to do this?

I have googled this term: 'Text Dependent Voicer Verification', but haven't found any simple solutions or algorithms.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Sensory has it:
http://www.sensory.com/products/technologies/trulyhandsfree/

Not sure if it is very accurate

Answer (score 0):

There are no simple solutions for such a complex problem. You can study algorithms involved with the following textbook [http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Speaker-Recognition-Homayoon-Beigi/dp/0387775919](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387775919)